# XSL quoting hell?

Tags: xslt

I have a simple XML file that looks like this:

```
<bases xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<marker>
   <name>Sample 1</name>
   <adr>Boston</adr>
   <state>Mass</state>
   <wiki>Link_1</wiki>
</marker>
<marker>
   <name>Sample 2</name>
   <adr>Essex</adr>
   <state>Vermont</state>
</marker>
```

If there is a `<wiki>` element, I want to create an HTML link (an `<a href..>` tag) in the output. If there is no `<wiki>` element, then output only the name. Here's my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="bases/marker">
      <xsl:sort select="name" />
        <tr>
        <td>
        <xsl:if test="wiki != ''">
                <a href="https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/<xsl:value-of select='wiki'/>">
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:if test="wiki != ''">
                </a>
        </xsl:if>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="adr"/>, <xsl:value-of select="state"/></td>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get a bunch of errors, starting with this one:

```
Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/<xsl:value-of select='wiki'/>">
```

Help!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/bases">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="marker">
            <xsl:sort select="name" />
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:if test="wiki">
                        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/{wiki}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                        </a>
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="adr"/>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To understand this, read about [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates).

Answer (score 1):

Use an [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#attribute-value-templates):

```
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/{wiki}"/>
```

Otherwise, you could construct the value of the attribute like this:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/<xsl:value-of select='wiki'/></xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

or like this:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('https://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/', wiki)"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```